# Difference between logger and root level in log4Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I just came across the two sections in log4net configiurations:

```xml
<logger name="File">
  <level value="All" />
</logger>
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
</root>
```

May I know what is the difference of specifying levels at logger and root tags? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`root` means all logs in the application, and `logger` allows to refer to a certain kind of log. Using them you can change the log configuration only for cetain logs. Look your sample with comments:

```xml
<!-- Set root logger level to INFO-->
<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
</root>

<!-- Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package "File" -->
<logger name="File">
    <level value="WARN" />
</logger>
```

In this sample all logs are to INFO, and the the log of the type "File" (or named File) is WARN.

Comment: doing a simple `LogManager.GetLog("File")` would get me this logger?

Comment: @jaminator: Yes, thats it